# How to retrieve application config values in factories in zend framework 3 (zf3)?

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I can retrieve configurations in factory via

```
class MyControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface{

    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null) {   
        $config = $container->get('Config') ;
    }
}
```

but this does not contains what I've configured in `application.config.php.` 
How I can access application.config settings array in zf3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration from `application.config.php` is registered under `ApplicationConfig` service key which is registered when initializing ZF3 application with default behavior. So use the following code snippet in a factory method:

```
$configuration   = $container->get('ApplicationConfig');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for clarification

In ZF3, if you are creating any classes that need in your application, make them serviceable, make them available in your application via ServiceManager. ServiceManager implements a container which stores registered services. So how is that? ZF uses a method called factory (in short, it creates object). It helps store services into container. We can then pull services from that container using ServiceManager. Let's see how?

ServiceManager is itself a service.

So using a factory let's make ServiceManager instance available in a controller (For example, IndexController). So that we can get any service using it.

Application\Controller\IndexControllerFactory

```
<?php
    namespace Application\Controller;

    // This is the container 
    use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
    use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

    class IndexControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
    {
        public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = NULL)
        {   
           $serviceManager = $container->get('ServiceManager');
           return new IndexController($serviceManager);
        }    
     }
```

Let's configure it so that we can use it. Make the following change in the moudle.config.php

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\IndexController::class =>    Controller\IndexControllerFactory::class,
    ],
 ],
```

Once the IndexController instantiated by IndexControllerFactory (by above configurations) the ServiceManager instance becomes available through IndexController's constructor.